# env["rack.session"] is always empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack, rails-api

I am using rack, rack-openid gems with rails 4.2.1 and it raises an error `Rack::OpenID requires a session` cuz env["rack.session"] is empty. 
Any ideas why it is empty?

**Update**

I am using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api), not rails

Comment: If I remember correctly the defaul rails-API middleware stack doesn't include cookies

Comment: @FrederickCheung you are right, if I add `config.api_only = false` works fine. I tried to add session and cookie middleware, but getting `ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x4f529a0 not yet loaded` when I inspect the session in a controller